# Standalone WPF Filter Control

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, user-controls

Most WPF data grid controls around have an inbuilt ability to filter the data shown. I am interested in using that functionality, but disconnect from data grid usage.

I'm hoping to find a user control that will return an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` that I can use in a LINQ query. Does anyone know of such a user control?

Answer (score 5):

In WPF, filtering for built in controls is performed using a `CollectionView`. This `CollectionView` is then assigned as the `ItemsSource` of the collection control (anything derived from `ItemsControl`).

As of .NET 3.5 SP1, the filter property on the `CollectionView` class takes a delegate of type `Predicate<object>`. `Predicate<object>` appears to be essentially the same as `Func<object, bool>`, but the two are not directly compatible. You should be able to easily create a `Func<object, bool>` delegate to wrap the `Predicate<object>` delegate.

```
public static Func<object, bool> GetFuncFromPred(Predicate<object> pred)
{
    return (obj => pred.Invoke(obj));
}
```

You can call this on the filters in the `CollectionView`, and then use them in a LINQ query.

Example:

```
List<object> list = GetList();
CollectionView colView = new CollectionView(list);
ListBox lb = GetListBox();
lb.ItemsSource = colView;
colView.Filter = GetFilter();
var filteredItems = list.Where(GetFuncFromPred(colView.Filter));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I think your answer is a little off track. I'm looking for a WPF Control to provide the expression.

Comment: You may find a custom one that someone built, but there IS no built in WPF control that does this. Sorry. I was explaining how you could do this yourself if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any. We had to build our own.

We used a CollectionViewSource and added a default filter as well as the ability to replace the default with a custom filter.

Comment: Bummer. I'm thinking that might be the way to go. Were you able to build a control that used Generics and Reflection, or create hard coded filters per class?

Comment: We used a public dependency property of the type Predicat<object> and then set the filter property on a CollectionViewSource object, calling refresh as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try that : http://dotnetexplorer.blog.com/2011/04/07/wpf-itemscontrol-generic-staticreal-time-filter-custom-control-presentation/

This is a generic, dynamic, full XAML declarative itemscontrol filter user control. It can filter datagrid, listbox,combobox, etc...

The component uses precompiled link expression to retreive and compare objects values so it offers pretty good performances.

Hope this helps !

Comment: And in addition, you don't have to write any filtering logic nor C# code, juste declare your ItemsControl in XAML, bind it to any collection of any objects, declare (in XAML also) the collection children type and the properties on wich you want the filter to apply and here you go. It also support "AND/OR" switch mode, the "!" operand and can reference custom string format or converter to ensure that the object values are formated for the comparison in the same way as theyr are in the UI.